# windows authentication user coming up blank

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I'm attempting to setup windows authentication in an asp.net web application.

Running the following code in an aspx page does not return any info ..

```
User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

Here's what I've done so far:
The server is win 2008 r2. In IIS I've enabled Windows Authentication.
In the Advanced settings of Windows Authentication is Extended Protection:Off and Enable Kernel-mode authentication.

In the web.config of my app, I've got the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

in the system.web node.
In the pageload of the default aspx I have the following..

```
string userName=" ++ " + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + " ++ ";
ltrTest.Text = userName;
```

All it returns is " ++  ++ ".

Comment: What is the reasoning for the ++ on both ends?

Comment: Just a visual indicator so that worst case scenario, I get more than just a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do. In your development machine, when running your application locally, you'll need to disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication. To do this, you will need to click on your project properties. There, you should see Development Server (I click on my solution, then click the properties tab). You then change the Anonymous Authentication to Disabled and then Windows Authentication To Enabled.

You should then be able to use

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
ltrTest.Text = userName;
```

This should do it. Hope this helps.

EDIT: I have set up windows auth in a new app and published to IIS and displayed label as username.

Steps:

1)

```
   <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users = "?" />
    </authorization>
```

This is how I set up the webconfig. If you have

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

you will want to remove it.

2)Published to IIS

3)Opened site home in IIS and clicked on Authentication.

4)Disabled Anonymous Authentication and Enabled Windows Authentication. 
  Note: Windows Authentication is the only thing that is suppose to be enabled. If anything else is enabled(Impersontaion) disable it.

5)On local pc, navigated to the site, typed in credentials in log in prompt

That's it. With labels that I placed in the default.aspx page, I was able to see my username in the format of DOMAIN\User. I also displayed the authentication type and if user was authenticated.

This should work as I have just tested it out.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm attempting to get this going on the web server.

Comment: Still a bit confused. What version of IIS are you using? If you are running it locally, you're going to be using IIS Express if you are using Visual Studio. If you are publishing your site to an actual web server such as IIS7, you will still need to disable Anonymous Authentication, possibly even Forms Authentication and enable Windows Authentication. More information is needed if you're not debugging locally. If you are debugging locally, does the code above work but not when it's published?

Comment: I'm publishing to an IIS server, not locally.  On the IIS Server, keeping Windows Authentication Enabled, If I disable Anonymous Authentication, I get a login dialog>  I attempt to login 3 tries, then a 401 error.  When I disable Anonymous Authentication, I do not get the login dialog, the page displays with no user information as mentioned above. Also, ASP.Net Impersonation, Basic Authentication, Digest Authentication and Forms Authentication are all disabled.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. See if that helps. I set a new app up from scratch to use Windows Auth and it worked.

Comment: I disabled Anonymous Authentication..only Windows Authentication is enabled, and tried as you suggested, with the same results..3 tries, then a 401 error.  Below is the contents of my webconfig.<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple setup. Are there any settings other settings on the server that could keep this from working?

Comment: When you go into IIS, are you changing the Authentication for (for example, my application is under Default Web Site) website or the web application? I should have mentioned that I expanded Default Web Site and then selected my Web Application and changed the Authentication there. That is really my last idea of what could be happening. You might have enabled and disabled everything under the site and not the application.

Comment: i had it setup as a website.  i tried as a web application and got the same results.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times, this finally fixed my issue!